# Law of total probability for joint events

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable with CDF $F_X$ and let $A$ be any event on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. Then the law of total probability is defined to be $\mathbb{P}(A)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(A|X=x)dF_X(x)$.

Now my question is if this formula also applies to joint events? What would this formula reduce to for the general case and why?

For example consider $\mathbb{P}(X_2<X_1,Y_2<Y_1)$ where $(X_1,Y_1)$ and $(X_2,Y_2)$ are independant vectors. I would define $A=(X_2<X_1,Y_2<Y_1)$ and then apply the formula as such:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_2<X_1,Y_2<Y_1)
&&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(X_2<X_1,Y_2<Y_1|X_1=x,Y_1=y)dF_{X_1,Y_1}(x,y)
&&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{P}(X_2<x,Y_2<y)dF_{X_1,Y_1}(x,y)
&&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}F_{X_2,Y_2}(x,y)dF_{X_1,Y_1}(x,y)
\end{align}

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!